# How to Access NavigationController inside a UITabBarController

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have this UITabBarController that loads 4 tabs (each is a UIViewController).

In my UITabBarController, NavigationController is always null, but I really need that object.

How to access it?

Answer (score 1):

Each tab in your TabController should contain it's own UINavigationController, with the view for that tab pushed onto it.  You have to explicitly create and assign the nav controllers.  That way each tab will have it's own independent navigation, which is what I assume that you want.

Your tab controller's NavigationProperty controller will be null, unless your TabController is contained within a NavigationController, which is generally a bad idea.